# The highest of: and / or

Tags: grammar

Do I use **and** or **or** with the highest?

Is it:

> The highest of a and b.

or

> The highest of a or b.

?

Comment: Why do you want to use *or* without any comparison? Should be "The highest of a <list>, which is joined by *and*. "Which is higher, A or B?" is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, a group of objects follows after 'the highest of':

> Mount Harvard is *the highest of* the Collegiate Peaks of Colorado and the third highest peak of the Rocky Mountains. <sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mountain_peaks_of_the_Rocky_Mountains)</sup>

Therefore, I'd go for 'and' in your case, but it still sounds unnatural to me.

For numbers or quantities, it is more common to talk about the **maximum**:

> What does this function return? The maximum of A and B.

Comment: I agree. The maximum sounded right to me. Thank you.